# C++ Compiler passing by reference without me telling it to?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I made a program earlier in the year that taught us how to use arrays. Just recently I was taught about the use of pointers and structures in C++. Now that I have that knowledge and understanding (or so I think), I am confused to how my earlier program managed to work!

Before I say more, here is the program code:

https://pastebin.com/AYyv2Bzt

special attention to my askSales function as it leaves me baffled

```
void askSales(int salesArray[], string namesArray[])
{
for (int counter = 0; counter <= NUM_OF_POS; counter++)
  {
      cout << "How many jars of " << namesArray[counter] << "sold? : ";
      cin >> salesArray[counter];

      while (salesArray[counter] < 0 )
            {
            cout << endl << "You cannot enter a negative number for sales. If no jars were\nsold please enter 0. Please answer prompt again."
                 << endl << endl
                 << "How many jars of " << namesArray[counter] << "sold? : ";
            cin >> salesArray[counter];
            }
   }
}
```

**Heres what I am confused about:**

How in the world is my program able to modify the contents of the arrays passed to askSales when those arguments are not passed by reference?

Comment: Because when used in an expression (such as passing as an argument to a function) native arrays convert to pointers to the first element. This is C/C++ parameter-passing of arrays 101, so check your reference materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function declaration and in the calls to it you get [array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay).

This means your function is exactly equivalent to this:

```
void askSales(int* salesArray, string* namesArray)
```

And that obviously doesn't pass the array by value and create a new copy of the array, it passes a pointer to the original array. Which gives the effect of passing by reference (because the pointer refers to the original array outside the function).

Comment: Ohkay......holy crap im dumb...did not know that arrays decays to pointers when passed into functions. So here is another quik qq : Are arrays the only things that decay to pointers? && How does one go about passing an Array as a value if they so desired to not let the function affect the array on the outside?

Comment: Functions also decay to pointers. You cannot pass arrays or functions by value. You have to wrap them in an object type to turn them into values.

Answer (score 3):

Plain C++ arrays are never passed by value on their own. They *decay* into pointers.

In the declaration/definition of a function, the syntax `T id[]` (or even with a number, such as `T id[4]`) is just syntactic sugar for `T *id`. It's exactly the same thing.

When passing an array to a function, it is implicitly converted ("decays") to a pointer to its first element.

---

Note that the above only applies to plain arrays. In modern C++, you have the alternative of using `std::array<T, n>` to declare an array of `n` objects of type `T`. Since `std::array` is a class, it behaves like a class and does not have any such decay rules. Such an array is actually copied when passed by valaue.